# OpenCV Template Matching: Restrict search area

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, template-matching

I have working OpenCV template matching code made with python. Now I am searching for a way to tell OpenCV to search only in a supplied area (x, y, w, h), is that possible?

Regards,
Philip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
roi = image[y:y+h , x:x+w]

cv2.matchTemplate(roi, templ, ...
```

Comment: So technically I just create a new image out of the original and then search in it?

Comment: it's just a subrect of the original image ( so, not a copy, if you were asking this )

Comment: Problem is I get a NameError: global name 'y' is not defined

Comment: hey, ofc. you've got to replace x,y,w,h with your numbers there

Comment: I don't get it. So I if I have a image called template that is made with cv2.imread() I just do roi = template[10,10,10,10] and then I have a 10x10 sized chunk starting at coordinates X:10 and Y:10?

Comment: make it:  template[10:20, 10:20]   then

Comment: Please, complete your answer with a full formula and ideally a working example.